# Möbius transform example explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, mobius-transformation

If a Möbius transform is a map that goes from the extended complex plane to the extended complex plane, given by some $\omega = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$, where $ad - bc \neq 0$. In my notes, underneath the definition, I have:

Ex: $ \frac{1z + 2}{2z + 4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

How does this work? Isn't ad - bc = 0? Or have I made some kind of mistake in writing down the notes properly? Where does the fraction come from?

Comment: The example illustrates why we want $ad - bc\neq 0$ since we would like these to not be constant functions.

Comment: I think the "ex" is probably the reason that we require $ad-bc\neq 0$ - you get problematic cases if $ad-bc=0$, and this is an example of why it is problematic. (Another example,  $c=d=0$ is obviously problematic.)

Comment: Where does the 1/2 come into it then?

Comment: $2z+4=2(1z+2)$, so $\frac{1z+2}{2z+4}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your definition, the map is not a Möbius transform. As for how it's $1/2$? $2z+4=2(1z+2)$.